# Scala lift's CssBind.calculate does not work for Seq

Tags: scala, css-selectors, lift

i'm having trouble while testing Css selectors.

if i have, let's say, the following CssSel:

```scala
val mySelector = ".class *" #> "my awesome super String"
```

the following works:

```scala
mySelector.stringSelector.openOr("") /* Returns ".class"*/
mySelector.calculate(NodeSeq.Empty) /* Returns "my awesome super String"*/
```

but if i have the following CssSel:

```scala
val mySeletorWithSeq = ".class" #> Seq(".number" #> 1, ".number" #> 2)
```

the following works differently:

```scala
mySeletorWithSeq.stringSelector.openOr("") /* Returns ".class"*/
mySeletorWithSeq.calculate(NodeSeq.Empty) /* Returns an NodeSeq (size 2) of empty Nodes*/
```

What i wanted was to have access to the Seq in the right side of my CssSelector, it really should be easier to acess, just like the left side ("mySelector.stringSelector"), other than having to use the calculate function.

Any tips/teaching on how i can do it?

tons of thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in order to chain selectors you need to use the `&` symbol.

Try

```scala
val mySeletorWithSeq = ".class" #> {
  ".number" #> 1 &
  ".number" #> 2
}
```